# whats the fastest way to merge 2 arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have 2 arrays:

```
1st array {0=> "google", 1=> "apple", 2=> "microsoft"}
2nd array {0=> "awesome", 1=> "sucks", 2=> "oh man!"}
```

now what I want is to merge the 2 arrays in this form:

```
array {"google"=>"awesome", "apple"=>"sucks", "microsoft"="oh man!"}
```

whats the most efficient way to do this?
thanks

Comment: looks more like ruby hash than php array ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `array_combine — Creates an array by using one array for keys and another for its values`

```
$a = array(0=> "google", 1=> "apple", 2=> "microsoft");
$b = array(0=> "awesome", 1=> "sucks", 2=> "oh man!");

$c = array_combine($a, $b);

print_r($c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with **array_combine**..??try like this

```
$array3 = array_combine($array1, $array2); 
print_r($array3);
```

you will get like

```
array {"google"=>"awesome", "apple"=>"sucks", "microsoft"="oh man!"}
```

and you can also try with "**array_merge**" like

```
$array3 = array_merge($array1, $array2);
print_r($array3);
```